# Axios is getting the data but I don't seem to be displaying it correctly on the front end

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

Hi So I have tested everything and it is working. Axios is indeed pulling the data I need. I am currently trying to implement it in my render () but nothing seems to be appearing. I am not sure what is wrong as I am also not getting any errors. Below is what I have to display the data in the front.

```
const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!userData.user)
        history.push("/");



    const checkAdmin = async () => {    
        let currAdmin = userData.user.adminId; 

        const adminRes = await Axios.get('http://localhost:9000/Links/all?currAdmin=' + currAdmin);  
        setLinks(adminRes.data);   
    };
    checkAdmin();
}, []);

return (
    <div className="dashboard">
        <Header />
        <br /><br />

        <h3>Admin Type:</h3>
        <ListGroup className="linkList">
            {links.map(e => (    
                <ListGroup.item key={e.adminId}>
                    {e.links}
                </ListGroup.item>
            ))}
        </ListGroup>

    </div>

);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `adminRes.data` is an array?

Comment: Are you sure adminRes.data returns what you are expecting?

Comment: @kunquan I believed I initialized it as an array with the useState function I'm fairly new to this sorry. I have seen people do something such as `let adminRes = []` Although I am not entirely sure if that is correct or even applies to my problem

Comment: @lissettdm Testing the HTTP link with axios does show me I am getting the data I want `currAdmin` and the entire `axios.get` call is for sure working. I am assuming I am not doing the right thing with the data being sent back

Comment: Show us the response of `axios.get()`. I think the problem is either you don't get your data back or your data shape is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving checkAdmin out of useEffect?

```
const [links, setLinks] = useState([]);

const checkAdmin = async () => {    
   let currAdmin = userData.user.adminId; 

   const adminRes = await Axios.get('http://localhost:9000/Links/all?currAdmin=' + currAdmin);  
        setLinks(adminRes.data);   
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (!userData.user)
        history.push("/");

    checkAdmin();
}, []);

return (
    <div className="dashboard">
        <Header />
        <br /><br />

        <h3>Admin Type:</h3>
        <ListGroup className="linkList">
            {links.map(e => (    
                <ListGroup.item key={e.adminId}>
                    {e.links}
                </ListGroup.item>
            ))}
        </ListGroup>

    </div>

);
```